# Ellipsis site in information structure

Tags: ellipsis

My understanding was always that any elided material does not count for information structure of the overt sentence, naturally. That is, the material has to be *given* to be elided --- but it cannot be a part of topic or focus. A fellow linguist has recently made a remark that seemed to indicate that it may not be the case. I didn't have a chance to clarify it with him.

So my question is: Are there any data and/or analyses suggesting that elided material may count in the *computation* of information structure?

Comment: Surely that's a matter for formal information structure theories, rather than linguistics per se. It is certainly true, however, that a great deal of presupposition and frame analysis is often required to decode the information in the overt sentence. Much of this decoding is cued through various ellipses, among other things.